# What is a list of HTML elements that load external resources? (HTML Email)

Tags: html, html-email

I'm looking for a list of elements that can load external resources given no additional DOM manipulation via JavaScript is allowed. I am trying to host e-mails from third parties with an HTML viewer and when that happens, I need to remove any resources that load automatically so that only the base HTML is displayed even if that makes the content show up incorrectly.

So far the list is:

```
<img />
<embed />
<object />
<link />
<script />
<audio />
<video />
<style type="text/css">selector { property: uri('') }</style>
```

Are there any other elements or patterns I need to take into account to prevent third-party resources from being loaded. And, yes, I am familiar with the sandbox attribute, but we require support for older browsers as well.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html

Comment: i have a slightly similar requirement only that the email is in `string` format that contains `html` tags. What I wanted is a regex. Did you have any luck in this?

Answer (score 0):

`<img>` has universal support and is the standard for referencing external images in email. Images can also be displayed in `<style>` using `url:www.website.com/image.jpg`.

`<link>` has [decent support](https://www.caniemail.com/features/html-link/) for referencing things like webfonts and external stylesheets.

`<object>`, `<video>`, and `<audio>` are supported by a few clients, but not many.

`<svg>` is another that has *some* support that's worth watching out for.

I don't believe `<embed>` or `<script>` are supported in email clients. they're generally stripped from any markup.