# Which HTML tags and their attributes can load external resources?

Tags: html, browser, cross-browser

I want to write a proxy that loads a website from a third party server and then transforms its source .html to make *its* client load these resources from the proxy.

When `<script>`-tags are removed, which remaining tags can cause browsers to fetch resources from the server?

Example:

`<img>`'s `src` and `srcset` attributes.

Answer (score 3):

Right now, the following things come to mind:

```html
<iframe />
<object />
<img />
<picture />
<embed />
<object />
<link />
<script />
<audio />
<video />
<track />
```

Furthermore, you can use something like `background-image:url()` in any CSS-code to load something from the server, like say background images.

Here's a link for more information: [w3-reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics-embedded-content.html)

Comment: There should be a complete list somewhere, maybe in some specification/standards document. But I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437971/what-is-a-list-of-html-elements-that-load-external-resources-html-email